# Maven Unit Test FileNotFound Error

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, fileoutputstream

I created a Maven project that involves "writing out" a CSV file on completion.

I created a test class to generate a "mock/test" report file, but when running my unit test, when using the "mvn package" or "mvn test" commands, I get this error:

```
28 Jan 2012 11:17:51,499 main DEBUG main.executors.ReportsExecutor:111  - Finished processing documents in 0.0 hours
28 Jan 2012 11:17:51,516 main ERROR main.utilities.FileWriterObject:279  - writeToADelimitedFile: reports/reportResults_1_28_2012_11.17.515.csv (No such file or directory) APPEND VALUE: false
28 Jan 2012 11:17:51,517 main ERROR main.executors.ReportsExecutor:170  - java.io.FileNotFoundException: reports/reportResults_1_28_2012_11.17.515.csv (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: reports/reportResults_1_28_2012_11.17.515.csv (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:102)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:61)
    at
```

Keep in mind that the "APPEND VALUE: false" output is just a debug statement letting me know that the "append" boolean parameter in the FileWriter constructor is false, in order to "create" a new file with the respective file name.

Now, in production, it works just fine.  It's just my unit tests that aren't working.  Is there some "root test" directory that I'm not configuring?

I'm quite green to Maven.  Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you post the relevant code snippet - `writeToADelimitedFile` method in `FileWriterObject`?  Looks like maven is unable to create the file

Answer (score 1):

Maven sets a property called "basedir" which is convenient to use in unit tests. I wrote a quick unit test and this works for me in both maven and in Eclipse:

```
public class ReadAndWriteToTargetDirectoryTest extends Assert {

    public static final String TEST_STRING = "Testing";

    @Test
    public void testReadWrite() {
        File file = new File(System.getProperty("basedir", ".") + File.separator + "target", "mavenTest.txt");

        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
            System.out.println("File: " + file.getCanonicalPath());
            writer.write(TEST_STRING);
            writer.close();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            reader.close();
            assertTrue(line.equals(TEST_STRING));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            fail(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

When using System.getProperty(...) to get the "basedir" system property be sure to set the default parameter to "." so that you can run the unit test in Eclipse as well:

```
System.getProperty("basedir", ".")
```

Comment: To be environment indepentend it should also be possible to use the standard java property [user.dir](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29)

Comment: This doesn't help me, because the deployed application will not have a "target" sub-directory.  This is why I do not receive this error on the deployed server.  It's only when I try to run the test to write the respective file locally or via "mvn test" on the build server.

Comment: @Rick Sorry it didn't help. I guess I am confused with what you are asking.

Comment: @BenjaminLinus No worries.  Perhaps others are as well.  In production, the "writing" of the file works just fine.

However, when I run "mvn tests" it can't seem to write/create the new file.  This happens on my local machine and on our Hudson build server.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can't tell Maven to run its tests "relative" to a directory, other than the one from where I ran the command "mvn test."

So if I'm trying to write to a file in a directory "relative" to the project root directory, I need to have my Java class, i.e. the one doing the writing, check to make sure the respective directory exists before writing it.

The reason why I didn't do this originally is because I have my ant-deployment.xml file build out the needed directories I need for my implementation, i.e. target/logs, target/resources, etc. So when I run my deployed app, I don't have this issue.

I was hoping that I could tell maven, i.e. "mvn -Dbase.dir=target test", but apparently I cannot.